# Strange lamp behaviour

Tags: electrical, lamp, multiway-switch, relay

I have an exterior lamp that is controlled by a standard switch and a 'timed-relay' (I push a button and light stays on for 3 minutes), I think those two are wired in parallel as if the lamp is on and I operate the relay button it clicks (so it has power). 
If I switch OFF the breaker and the switch is ON the led bulb, instead of staying dark, starts blinking, but if I switch the light on by the relay then I switch off the breaker, light stays off (in this situation if I flip on the switch, bulb stays dark). What can be?

PS: I'm in EU (230V), my earthing is TT, my breakers are double pole, my main breaker is RCD.

Comment: What happens if you use a standard (non-LED) light bulb?

Comment: With CFL or halogen the light stays off (same bulb in other lamps is fine)

Comment: Can you give us a diagram of how the wiring is routed here?

Comment: Sorry but I can't (cannot reach junction box).